# The GET method is not supported for route submitdata. Supported methods: POST

Tags: javascript, laravel

**js Code**

```
document.getElementById('submitdata').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Submitting all data');
    
        var rowsData = [];
    
        document.querySelectorAll('#itemTable tbody tr').forEach(function (row) {
            var item = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').textContent;
            var price = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent;
            var quantity = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').textContent;
    
           
            rowsData.push({ item: item, price: price, quantity: quantity });
        });
    
        
        var csrfToken = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    
      
        console.log('CSRF Token:', csrfToken);
        console.log('Rows data:', rowsData);

        fetch('/submitdata', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ rows: rowsData }),
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log('All data submitted successfully:', data);
        
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error submitting all data:', error);
            });
        });
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/submitdata', [OrderController::class, 'submitdata']);
```

**OrderController**

```
public function submitdata(Request $request)
    {
        
        try {
        $rows = $request->input('rows');
        \Log::info('Received POST request to /submitdata');
    
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            
            $order = new Order([
                'item' => $row['item'],
                'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
                'price' => $row['price'],
                'total' => $row['total'],
            ]);
    
           
            $order->save();
        }
        \Log::info('Data submitted successfully');
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Data submitted successfully']);
    }catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::error('Error processing data:', [
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'trace' => $e->getTraceAsString(),
        ]);
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Internal Server Error'], 500);
    }
```

data doesn't submit to the database. I provided POST method but show an error like above.show on console like this.
**POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/submitdata 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ cashier:208
cashier:227 Error submitting all data: Error: HTTP error! Status: 500
at cashier:218:19**

Comment: You're mentioning both "The GET method is not supported for route submitdata. Supported methods: POST" and the 500 error at the end of your question. Which one is the actual problem? Please provide the stack trace for the server error.

Comment: Maybe you have duplicate url in web.php for GET method. If you have duplicate routes with same url Laravel will take first one regardless you have different route names.

Comment: i checked. but only this url in web.php

Comment: when click on http://127.0.0.1:8000/submitdata, show 'The GET method is not supported for route submitdata. Supported methods: POST' @Severin